# How to select which form to load in JSF 2?

Tags: jsf

I would like to build a JSF application that has several forms on its page.

I have 2 XHTML pages: first.xhtml and second.xhtml (login and register).

When I load first.xhtml I want it to have "goTOAnotherPage" button **only**, that will redirect to second.xhtml, then I want to return to first.xhtml but to load "form2" instead of "form1".

I want to return to first.xhtml and not go to a third page because I want to have additional forms on first.xhtml and I don't wan't to duplicate the code of those additional forms.

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:commandButton id="f1ID"
                     value="goTOAnotherPage"
                     action="goTOAnotherPage" >
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:form id="form2">
    <h:outputText value = "in form 2" />
</h:form>
```

Please help me,

Thank you.

Comment: Just wrap the contents of each form in some panel and selectively render based on a request parameter

Comment: I use @SessionScoped so I can't use request parameter. I added to formes: <h:form id="form1" rendered="#{thebean.logedIn != 'logedIn'}"> <h:form id="form2" rendered="#{thebean.logedIn == 'logedIn'}">, but then only the form that returned true at first load returned, even after the condition is false.